# Why does the while loop in JS stops even when condition is met?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple Todo list program in JavaScript.

***Expected Behavior:-***

If the user types `new` they should be asked what new item they want to add to the list.

If the user types `list`, every item in the array should be listed.

If the user types `quit`, the program ends.

If the user types anything else, they should be prompted again.

***Resultant Behavior:-***

Everything works, except when the user types anything else from the commands, the program closes automatically.

***Here is My JavaScript Code:-***

```
let want = prompt("What Do You Want To Do?");

let list = [];

let listItem = "";

while (want !== "quit") {
  if (want === "new") {
    listItem = prompt("Enter A Task You Want To Add");
    console.log(`${listItem} added to your todo list.`);
    list.push(listItem);
    want = prompt("What Do You Want To Do?");
  } else if (want === "list") {
    console.log("*******");
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(list[i]);
    }
    console.log("*******");
    want = prompt("What Do You Want To Do?");
  }
}
console.log("Okay You Quit");
```

I have set the while loop to continue until the user types `quit`, so why does it stops???

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program does not *close*, but it loops infinitely - when the input is neither `new` nor `list` nor `quit`, no statements inside the `while` loop execute. It's like:

```
while (want !== "quit") {
  // nothing
}
```

so the loop keeps executing forever.

While you could add an `else { want = prompt(...`, it'd be nicer to write only *one* of those at the end of the loop, for all conditions.

```js
let want = prompt("What Do You Want To Do?");

let list = [];

let listItem = "";

while (want !== "quit") {
  if (want === "new") {
    listItem = prompt("Enter A Task You Want To Add");
    console.log(`${listItem} added to your todo list.`);
    list.push(listItem);
  } else if (want === "list") {
    console.log("*******");
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      console.log(list[i]);
    }
    console.log("*******");
  }
  want = prompt("What Do You Want To Do?");
}
console.log("Okay You Quit");
```